# StaticLayout get number of displayed chars like Paint.breakText

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a StaticLayout to draw some multiline text.
StaticLayout is convenient because it handles all the text breaking and new lining for me...

```
canvas.save();
canvas.clipRect(rect);

canvas.translate(rect.left, rect.top);

staticLayout.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

When I just draw a single line I use canvas.drawText() in combination with Paint.breakText to detemine the number of chars I can paint on my available space...

Now I need to know the exact numer of chars that fit in my StaticLayout so that I can paint the rest of the chars to another StaticLayout.

Unfortunaltely I haven't found a method that tells me how many chars fit in it.

Is there something available to get this?

Cheers,
Stefan